# Output shows something like Series([], ), how to fix this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, for-loop, series

I have a dataframe that looks like the below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'reference_id':['012ABH3', '012ABD44', '023HBA3', '032IHJK4', '543BHKI0'], 'link1': ['http://ll.abc.com/LNLDSOUYsda5443', 'http://ll.abc.com/KJBAKJBADndkja1223', 'http://ll.abc.com/KJADBDKAJB9973Fsdad', 'http://ll.abc.com/KAHSBAKHBjj*&*', 'http://ll.abc.com/JBKJBKJBDSwe77676']})
df
  reference_id                                  link1
0     012ABH36      http://ll.abc.com/LNLDSOUYsda5443
1     012ABD44   http://ll.abc.com/KJBAKJBADndkja1223
2     023HBA35 https://ll.abc.com/KJADBDKAJB9973Fsdad
3     032IHJK4       http://ll.abc.com/KAHSBAKHBjj*&*
4     543BHKI0   https://ll.abc.com/JBKJBKJBDSwe77676
```

I am trying to write a for loop and get some information from each link in the dataframe.

```
for i in df['link1']:
    if str(i).startswith('http'):
        link = i
        link = re.sub(r'(\w+)(?=.*:)', 'http', link)
        rid = df.loc[df['link1'] == link, 'reference_id']
        rid = pid.to_string(index=False)
        print(rid)
```

But along the process I also need to print the referenceid of the respective link into a list of output values. When I do this I notice I get something as show below.

```
012ABH36
012ABD44
Series([], )
Series([], )
543BHKI0
```

I don't understand what does Series([], ) mean. Can someone explain what could be wrong with this and how can I get rid of the Series([], )? How do I get the correct referenceid per link information of the link1 column?

Comment: `url` is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I identified the cause of the issue through testing some combinations.

In my script, I write the below line

```
link = re.sub(r'(\w+)(?=.*:)', 'http', link)
```

This is convert all the links that have https into http. But when this is done and when I try to fetch the corresponding referenceid, it notices that the link is wrong. Hence it doesnt print the referenceid. Infact the first answer given by @nixon was correct. Thanks for pointing in the right direction